# Bootstrap Carousel Don't start from the beginning

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am  implementing a fancy survey with carousel.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel" style="vertical-align: center">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        ...
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="n"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            page 1
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            page 2                            
        </div>

        ...

        <div class="item">
            page n
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>                    
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">                    
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make carousel behave more like a sliding window which mean that it is not possible to go in an n-element carousel:

- from Page 1 to Page n
- from Page n to Page 1

**EDIT**
Somehow it seems that i discribed the problem not well enought. So i try better:

So first of all the carousell is in its original purouse meant for displaying pictures:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

i know use different forms inside each "Page" of the carousel.
You can go to the next "Page" of a carousel by clicking on the button on the right or to the last if you click the button on th right.

Now my only problem is - since this shall become a survey - that when Page one with my first question loads, a user can click the button on the left and will go to the end of the carousel (last page/page n).

Is it possible to disable this feature?

Comment: Please follow [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) add a snippet or fiddle so we could help you..

Comment: Then i feel really stupid right now... i thought that my question would be pretty clear, as long as you know how the carousell feature works. I will try to rewrite the text. Maybe I am not using the right words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are more elegant solutions, but this might get you started:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nb90bd9y/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="s1" class="slide">
          <div class="shead">Slide Title 1</div>
          <div class="sbody">Here is body of slide 1 with questions</div>
          <div class="sfoot"><button>Next</button></div>
        </div><!-- .slide -->
        <div id="s2" class="slide">
          <div class="shead">Slide Title 2</div>
          <div class="sbody">Here is body of slide 2 with questions</div>
          <div class="sfoot"><button>Next</button></div>
        </div><!-- .slide -->
        <div id="s3" class="slide">
          <div class="shead">Slide Title 3</div>
          <div class="sbody">Here is body of slide 3 with questions</div>
          <div class="sfoot"><button>Next</button></div>
        </div><!-- .slide -->
        <div id="s4" class="slide">
          <div class="shead">Slide Title 4</div>
          <div class="sbody">Thank you for taking this survey</div>
        </div><!-- .slide -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

**JS:**

```
var cnt=1;
$(function(){

    $('body').css({'background':'wheat'});
    $('#s'+cnt).css({'margin-left':0});
  $('button').click(function(){
      $('#s'+cnt).animate({
        marginRight:'100%'
      },500);
        cnt++;
      $('#s'+cnt).animate({
        marginLeft:'0%'
      },500,function(){
            //reset slide position, in case you wish to add a "Go Back one slide" btn
            $('#s'+cnt-1).css({'margin-left':'100%'});
      });
  });

});//END document.ready
```

**CSS:**

```
html,body{height:500px;width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
div{position:relative;}
.row{height:400px;width:100%;}
.slide{position:absolute;top:0;margin-left:100%;height:100%;width:100%;padding:20px;}
.shead{height:50px;width:100%;color:#aaa;background:#222;}
.sbody{height:300px;width:100%;padding:20px;}
.sfoot{height:50px;width:100%;}
.sfoot button{padding:12px 20px;background:darksteelgrey;color:#888;}
#s1{color:white;background:darkcyan;}
#s2{color:yellow;background:red;}
#s3{color:#333;background:palegreen;}
#s4{color:yellow;background:blue;font-size:2rem;}
```